# Its possible detach a entity in a listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.2

I have a entity with a price property in a form. In a update i want cancel the changes for this entity.

This is my code in preUpdate event listener:

```
if($entityManager->contains($entity)) {
    $entityManager->detach($entity);
    $uow  = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
    $meta = $entityManager->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
}
```

But in a test a get this error message:

1) WebFactory\PriceListBundle\Tests\Entity\PriceListTest::testCreateProduct
Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: Entity WebFactory\Bundle\PriceListBundle\Entity\PriceList@000000005f6fc4da0000000028ff97b1 is not managed. An entity is managed if its fetched from the database or registered as new through EntityManager#persist

Comment: Yes, its possible to detach in a listener... as you've just proven.

Comment: What do you meant with In a update i want cancel the changes for this entity?